# ThinkingSphinx: filter on a boolean column of an association

Tags: associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I see no reason why this shouldn't work, but I get no results. A `Contact` has many `OrganizationContacts`. And `OrganizationContact` has a boolean field `primary`. I've added a filter on this field as shown below.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :organization_contacts, :dependent => :destroy

  define_index do
    has organization_contacts(:primary), :as => :primary_contacts

    set_property :delta => true
  end
end
```

In a debugging session I can see that I do indeed have a `Contact` with an `OrganizationContact` that is listed as `primary`:

```
(rdb:1) p Contact.first.organization_contacts.first.primary
true
```

But if I do a `ThinkingSphinx` search using that filter, I get nothing:

```
(rdb:1) p Contact.search :with => { :primary_contacts => true }
[]
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crickets chirp. Alas, we came up with a work around.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :primary_organization_contacts, :class_name => "OrganizationContact", :foreign_key => "contact_id", :conditions => { :primary => true }
  has_many :organization_contacts, :dependent => :destroy

  define_index do
    has primary_organization_contacts(:id), :as => :primary_organization_contacts

    set_property :delta => true
  end
end
```

Searching for them is the interesting part. If I want records with no primary organization contacts:

```
Contact.search :with { :primary_organization_contacts => 0 }
```

If I want records with at least one primary organization contact:

```
Contact.search :without { :primary_organization_contacts => 0 }
```

It makes me feel dirty and confused but it does the job.